# use maxmind data like statcounter it is possible

Tags: php, licensing, maxmind

I found that in https://www.maxmind.com/en/license_agreement

How you may not use the GeoIP Data

You may not use the GeoIP Databases to develop a product or service for
sale, distribution, display to, or use by others outside your company.

i want to use data in my website user can check their website stat like visitor location. uniuqe visitor return visitor. it is possible. like statcounter

i want worlds country, state, city, and timezone by ip which database is perfect for me.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 1):

> You may not use the GeoIP Databases to develop a product or service
>   for sale, distribution, display to, or use by others outside your
>   company.

Says it all. You can use it in your own website but not in other peoples website, or to provide a service to other people.

But you shouldn't post this question here. Have you asked MaxMind?

The License Agreement also says:

> Access and use the GeoIP Databases, provided that devices outside your
>   company cannot directly query or access the databases.

I think it is clear that the information in the database is meant for your use only, and not to be used to analyse the visitor of your users (customers?).

Alternatively, you may license their GeoIP2 Precision services for resale or redistribution.

https://www.maxmind.com/en/geoip2-precision-services

Comment: i already asked maxmind before 1 minute and waiting for reply

i want to place on only my site........... and i will give user to password like statcounter so they can see their website stat

IT is possible ?

i  want to use only one site

Comment: One or many sites is not the issue. The information in the database can be used by you, not by others through you.

Comment: yes i saw that cost $0.0004 per query* GeoIP2 Precision 

So 1000 user cost 10,000 * 0.0004 = 4$ right ?

Comment: Alternatively, you may use [GeoLite2](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/geolite2/), which is licensed under CC BY-SA.

Comment: Maxmind tell me that it is not permitted to use like statcounter.
it is permitted only Geoip2 precision services and it's charge 20$ per 50,000 quary. I think my dream will break i want to track ip to location but there are not good services. IS IP2Location is good ?

Comment: You mean: No good free services with unlimited usage. That's probably because it is a lot of work, and costs money, to provide these services. US$ 20 for 50.000 queries is really not that much. Have a look at http://ipinfo.io it offers a 1000 queries a day for free and is based on GeoLite2 data created by MaxMind. A 1000 queries is a lot.